# MonoDroid Set Max Value for EditText

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Is there a way to set a maximum value for an edittext created in the activity?  For instance, if I didn't want the user to be able to enter a number higher than 8, etc.  The edittext is already set up as a numeric field.

```
et = new EditText(this);
et.InputType = (int)Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassNumber;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify allowed characters for an EditText using the [digits attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adigits):

```
<EditText
    android:digits="012345678"
    ... />
```

or from code:

```
editText.KeyListener = DigitsKeyListener.GetInstance("012345678");
```

**Edit:**

It sounds like what you're trying to do is go from an integer max value to the string representation Android needs. You could do something like this:

```
int maxValue = 8;
string digits = string.Join(string.Empty, Enumerable.Range(0, maxValue + 1));
editText.KeyListener = DigitsKeyListener.GetInstance(digits);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I should've given more detail on what I am doing. I am adding multiple edittexts while reading through a sql query and each numeric edittext will be restricted based on other numbers pulled in that query.  So the number by which I need to restrict the edittext will differ for each one.

Comment: Can I add the DigitsKeyListener as a range?  For example DigitsKeyListener.GetInstance(0 to whatever number my query pulls)?

Comment: You could just create the string based on the acceptable numbers you need each time.

Comment: Documentation for DigitsKeyListener is available here: http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T%3aAndroid.Text.Method.DigitsKeyListener%2fM

Comment: Thanks.  It may just be easier to validate the number after the fact.  I was just hoping there was some kind of SetMaxValue method hidden somewhere.  Your answer would technically work, so I will accept it.  Thanks again.

Comment: Added another sample that may help

Answer (score 4):

You should create a new class "InputFilterMinMax.java" in the same folder.

Then you should use filter:

```
textEdit = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
textEdit.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax("0", "180")});
```

in your class activity (I've set min as "0" and max as "180").

Code of InputFilterMinMax.java:

```
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;

public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

    private int min, max; //paramets that you send to class

    public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
        this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
        this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {   
        try {
            //int input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());
            String startString = dest.toString().substring(0, dstart);
            String insert = source.toString();
            String endString = dest.toString().substring(dend);
            String parseThis = startString+insert+endString;
            int input = Integer.parseInt (parseThis);
            if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                return null;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }     
        return "";
    }

    private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
        return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
    }
}
```

Source: [Android set min max value an edittext accepts](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2011/06/27/android-set-min-max-value-an-edittext-accepts/)

Comment: I need to do this, but how can this be used in Mono for Android (C#?). Do you have the C# version of this that works in Mono for Android or should I create this in Java and hook into it somehow? Please more help! :)

Comment: This code is somewhat broken: If you set min=10, you can't enter 20 into an empty field, because the first digit 2 is rejected.

Comment: @Hok the issue can be generalized to if dest + next number of input (source) < min this code blocks the input. Consider min = 15 and you are trying to input 145 if the current dest is "" or "1", you won't be able to. It also allows min = 15 and dest is currently "15", and you delete the 5, since dest still looks like 15.

Comment: In other words, this doesn't allow input that isn't within the range (deletions are still able to get around that), but is more restrictive than expected. Not every value in the range of [min, max] is considered valid input, which is unacceptable. You can get around that limitation if min = 1, as every valid start digit is >=1. I don't think this can be done correctly with InputFilter in general though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a general use min max range checked `EditText`, you should do something like the following (this assumes an `EditText` set for numeric input):

```
// This handles the minimum value check, this can't be done until AFTER you have given
// the user time to give input (aka not at a character-by-character resolution)
// One easy way to do this is to wait for the user to change focus
final int minimum = 15;
edit_text.setOnFocusChangeListener(
                new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFocusChange(View _, boolean has_focus) {
                        if (!has_focus && Integer.parseInt(edit_text.getText()) < minimum)
                            edit_text.setText(minimum + "");
                    }
                }
        );
// This handles the maximum value check, because the number increases monotonically with
// the addition of a digit, you can see that the user is inputting a number that is larger
// than the maximum number before the user tells you they are done
final int maximum = 180;
edit_text.setFilters(new InputFilters[] {
    new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int source_start, int source_end,
                                   Spanned destination, int destination_start, 
                                   int destination_end) {   
           try {
               String prefix = destination.toString().substring(0, destination_start);
               String insert = source.toString();
               String suffix = destination.toString().substring(destination_end);
               String input_string = prefix + insert + suffix;
               int input = Integer.parseInt(input_string);

               // Leaves input within the bound alone
               if (input <= max)
                   return null;
            } catch (NumberFormatException _) { }
            // Blocks insertions of "source" strings that make the string larger than the maximum     
            return "";
        }
    }
});
```

You can name these abstract classes if you want to reuse them multiple times.